# Typeahead.js within Bootstrap Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I'm trying to get typeahead to work within a bootstrap popover.  I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ydb2o79/

```
<p>This does not work</p>
<a data-placement='above' id="popover_button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" href='#'>Click</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
    <hr />
<p>This Works</p>
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
```

I don't believe it's a z-index issue.  It seems like typeahead.js isn't recognizing the input query.

Any ideas?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`shown.bs.popover`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events) method like this

```
$('#popover_button').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
    enableTypeAhead();
});
```

Leave your typeahead code in a method and call if after the popover is shown. It seems to have fixed the issue.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ydb2o79/2/). 
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj that was it!